# How to animate showing the next div element in a loop using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to code a jQuery animation that shows the next div in a loop. On hover, the animation should stop.

Currently, I have it working on click, but I don't know how to animate it.

Here is the code:

```js
var Text = $(".text");
Text.on("click", function() {
  var TextVisibility = $(this).css("display", "none");
  var NextText = TextVisibility.next(".text");
  if (!NextText.length) NextText = Text.eq(0);
  $(NextText).css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.text:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="text">Text Text Text</div>
  <div class="text">Link Link Link</div>
  <div class="text">Another Text</div>
</section>
```

What changes do I need so it will automatically change instead of having to click on the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a function to handle the display, and use `setInterval` to tell the code how often to call it.

**What you need to do:**

1. Variable to keep track of the current text, and initialise it to the first text element
2. Create our function for changing the text - this is based on your existing code, with the following changes
   a. If the `NextText` element is empty, then set it to the first element again
   b. When the next element is set up, set the `NextText` element to be the `currentText` element
3. Use `setInterval` to call our function as often as you want (e.g. every 2 seconds in the example below)

**The code to do this**, the comments reference the numbers above so you tell what it is doing:

```
// 1. Variable to keep track of the current text
// We initialise this to the first text element
var firstText = $(".text:first-child");
var currentText = firstText;

// 2. Create or function for changing the text
function changeText(){
   $(currentText).css("display", "none");
   var NextText = currentText.next(".text");

   // 2a. If its empty, get the first one again
   if (!NextText.length) NextText =  firstText;
   $(NextText).css("display", "block");

 // 2b. Set the current element to the new one
   currentText = NextText;
}

// call our changeText function every 2 seconds
var loopTimer = setInterval(changeText, 2000);
```

**To pause the animation on hover:**

1. Use the `hover` method on the elements (I've added a class `animatedText` to the container and used this)
2. On hover, clear our `loopTimer` to stop the animation using `clearInterval`
3. On the "mouseLeave" event, set up our `loopTimer` again to restart the animation
   NOTE: If you want the animation to restart with the *next* element, call `changeText()` first.

**Code to do this**:

```
$('.animatedText').hover(function(e){
    clearInterval(loopTimer);                         // stop animation
}, function(e){
    // If you want to that animation to restart with the NEXT element:
    changeText();
    loopTimer = setInterval( changeText, 2000);       // restart animation
})
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var animationDuration = 2000; // 2 seconds

// Variable to keep track of the current text
// We initialise this to the first text element
var firstText = $(".text:first-child");
var currentText = firstText;

function changeText(){
  $(currentText).css("display", "none");

  // Get the next text element
  var NextText = currentText.next(".text");
  // If its empty, get the first one again
  if (!NextText.length) NextText =  firstText;

  // Show the next element and set the current text
  $(NextText).css("display", "block");
  currentText = NextText;
}

// call our changeText function every "animationDuration" seconds
var loopTimer = setInterval( changeText, animationDuration);

$('.animatedText').hover(function(e){
    // stop animation
    clearInterval(loopTimer); 
}, function(e){
     // If you want animation to restart with the NEXT element:
    changeText();
    // restart animation
    loopTimer = setInterval( changeText, animationDuration);
})
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.text:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="animatedText">
  <div class="text">1 Text Text Text</div>
  <div class="text">2 Link Link Link</div>
  <div class="text">3 Another Text</div>
  <div class="text">4 More Text</div>
  <div class="text">5 Nearly Done</div>
  <div class="text">6 Last Text</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! It looks really good! But how is it possible to pause the animation on hover? I got it to change the speed on hover, but not to pause it. :/

Comment: @Anna_B I've updated my answer, sorry I forgot to add that first time :)

Comment: – It still works fine! But I have a question: Now the animation starts new after a hover. To just pause it is more complex? Or would this be easy to program?

Comment: @Anna_B This code restarts with whatever element is saved in the `currentText` element, it doesn't start from the beginning. I've updated the answer to show this - I've added more text elements and extra info in the console.log. If you're still having problems let us know!

Comment: I see. But after the hover it takes again 2 seconds to show the next div. Isn't it possible to take the remaining time (of the first 2 seconds) instead of "new" 2 seconds?

Comment: @Anna_B You can change the `currentText` to the `nextText`, the same way was you do in the `changeText` function - then it will start again with it. I'll take a look at updating my answer in a bit, just starting some of my own (real) work right now :)